# stopUpdatingLocation is not working in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I have developed both iPhone & iPad application which supports for iOS 5 and iOS 6

in that application i have grabbed user current location using `CLLocationManager.`

when i want to stop updating receiving GPS coordinates. I have called `stopUpdatingLocation`

method to stop calling `didUpdateToLocation` method. It was woking completely fine with iOS 5 and 6 But unfortunately its  not working with iOS 7.

Seems that `stopUpdatingLocation` method is not working .Any particular reason. ??

i had a keep a variable to monitor the life cycle of `didUpdateToLocation` method and stop executes it.

Comment: How about some code? It works fine in my iOS 7 stuff

Comment: double check if the method where you do `stopUpdatingLocation` actually ever gets called at all

Answer (score 0):

One thing might be possible is,

Your current location blue dot moving on your map is because you set the MKMapView's showsUserLocation to YES. It will track until you set it to NO.

Second thing,

You might be setting below thing to stop calling that method

```
locationManager = nil;
```

That does not stop monitoring, but what it does, not to refer the location manager, So now its not possible to stop monitoring.

Instead add below code & then see what happen

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
locationManager=nil;
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score -1):

@tdevoy  - Here is sample

```
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
    longtitude = location.coordinate.longitude;

    //stops updating current user location update
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Comment: Firstly, this isn't an answer - best to edit your original post.  Secondly, this code would never compile.  Last line should be: [manager stopUpdatingLocation]